# Exclude TypeScript-generated javascript files from Visual Studio 2015 search

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Prior to VS2015, projects required you to include files. Now, they're file-based. So if you use TypeScript, your generated javascript files (and map files) get included in your project, so for example searching will return twice the number of results.

Is there any way to avoid this, so the files are not included/searched?

Comment: Are you using a Visual Studio extension to compile TypeScript to JavaScript?

Comment: Don't think so. It's built into VS2015, isn't it? I see an extension listed but the option to uninstall is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set following options in `Find` / `Find and replace` dialogs:

`Find options -> Look at these file types = *.ts`